# should not access parent frame untill closes the child?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have two frames one parent and child.
the parent will invoke the child.

The program should not allow the user to access the parent until the user closes the child

How can i achive it?

Need a solution without hiding the parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`wx.Window.MakeModal()`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#MakeModal) method (`Frame` inherits from `Window`).